# Jquery checkbox is not checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

We are using Jquery and I am new to it. I have the following HTML and bootstarp code. The rows are dynamically created. Here I want to insure only one checkbox is checked at a time. i.e. the checkbox should be checked for the selected row and it should be unchecked for rest of the rows.

```
<div id="paymentTable" class="stripeTwoRows eligibilityARPaymentInfoWidth">
   <div class="row mx-0">
      <div class="col-2 px-1">
         <input id="memberARPaymentchkbox1" type="checkbox" name="memberARPaymentchkbox" onclick="resetPaymentDisplay(this);" payment="216001221" class="cursorPtr"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>216001221
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 px-1">00001</div>
      <div class="col-2 px-1">06/30/2016</div>
      <div class="col-2 px-1"></div>
      <div class="col-2 px-1">N</div>
      <div class="col-2 px-1 d-flex justify-content-end">$350.00-</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row mx-0">
      <div class="col-2 offset-4 px-1">0063016</div>
      <div class="col-2 offset-4 px-1 d-flex justify-content-end">$0.00</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row mx-0">
      <div class="col-2 px-1">
         <input id="memberARPaymentchkbox2" type="checkbox" name="memberARPaymentchkbox" onclick="resetPaymentDisplay(this);" payment="216001222" class="cursorPtr"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>216001222
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 px-1">00001</div>
      <div class="col-2 px-1">06/30/2016</div>
      <div class="col-2 px-1"></div>
      <div class="col-2 px-1">N</div>
      <div class="col-2 px-1 d-flex justify-content-end">$400.00-</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row mx-0">
      <div class="col-2 offset-4 px-1">0063016</div>
      <div class="col-2 offset-4 px-1 d-flex justify-content-end">$0.00</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I could able to uncheck all the rows, bu not able to check the checkbox of the selected row.

Tried with following Jquery code to check the checkbox, but not working.

```
$(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").attr("checked", true);
```

full code:

```
function resetPaymentDisplay(element) {
    var iCount = paymentTable.children.length;
    for (var iLoop = 0; iLoop < iCount; iLoop += 2) {

        paymentTable.children[iLoop].children[0].children[0].checked = false;


    }
     $(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").attr("checked", true);
    //$(this).attr("checked", true);


//  $(element).children().eq(0).prop('checked', true);
//  $(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").attr("checked", true);


}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate more ? which row ? where is selected row ? Also it would be good if you can create demo code

Comment: What does `$(this)` refer to? Can you post the full JS

Comment: The row that has the checkbox should checked if that row is selected and rest all checkboxes should be unchecked.

Comment: @Ashok.N it would be helpful if you posted more of your JS code so we could see the context.

Comment: @The Codesee added to the question. please take a look

Comment: @Dropout , edited the question now , please take a look

Comment: @Ashok.N I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `resetPaymentDisplay(this)` for the following element because of an onClick event

```
<input id="memberARPaymentchkbox2" type="checkbox" name="memberARPaymentchkbox" onclick="resetPaymentDisplay(this);" payment="216001222" class="cursorPtr">
```

In the `resetPaymentDisplay(this)` function it is referred to as `element` in the function arguments yet you are also using `$(this)` again on some lines.

If you pass the input element itself into the function, as you do because the `this` in your HTML code references your input element, you should be able to set it to checked just by the following function

```
function resetPaymentDisplay(element) {
    element.checked = true;
}
```

because you are working with a JavaScript object, not a jQuery object.

For the rest of the functionality, which is ensuring that you only have one of the checkboxes checked at any time you could use jQuery, but it can be easily done with vanilla JS as well. For the sake of this example let's go with jQuery that you were trying to use.

> Code block removed because it needed fixing. Please refer to the code block below.

Notes:

- it is important to differentiate between JavaScript objects and jQuery wrapped objects (the ones you get from jQUery searches like `$("#something")`. To help you not forget which is which it's common to prefix the jQuery wrapped objects with a dollar sign as you can see in the `$parent` and `$otherCheckboxes` example.
- `this` keyword always refers to something in the current scope.. it is a rather tricky concept to understand, especially if we're talking about JavaScript. The `this` in your HTML, `$(this)` in your JS code and even if you had a simple `this` in your JS code all reference different things.

Edit: Ok, to be honest I've provided the answer blindly without testing and made a very similar mistake as you did. The `$.each` function leaves you with JavaScript objects in `item`, instead of jQuery ones which I didn't realize. The final code for the function should look like this

```
function resetPaymentDisplay(element) {
    element.checked = true;

    var $parent = $('#paymentTable');
    var $otherCheckboxes = $parent.find(".cursorPtr");
    $otherCheckboxes.each(function(i, item) {
        if (item.id !== element.id) {
            item.checked = false;
        }
    });
}
```

Here is a working fiddle example for it: https://jsfiddle.net/g5t3s4uL/

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Learnt new things by your answer. When I try your solution, I am getting the error `otherCheckboxes is not defined` . Any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: Simple typo on my side, forgot about the dollar sign which I even pointed out, haha.. My bad, try now.

Comment: Also it would probably be better to turn off the input being checked by removing the `checked` attribute altogether. I will edit that in as well.

Comment: Done. It's now `$item.removeAttr("checked");`

Comment: now getting the error `$otherCheckboxes.each is not a function`

Comment: @Dropout you missed `$` near `parent` i.e : `$parent.find(".cursorPtr"); `

Comment: @Swati, Corrected `parent`  to `$parent.find(".cursorPtr");`. Now getting `$item.attr is not a function`.

Comment: Give me a second, I'm driving. I'll take a look at it and provide a jsFiddle.

Comment: @Ashok.N updated with a fiddle and fixed code, see explanation.

Comment: Also please consider using jQuery binding functions to define on click actions instead of calling them from HTML, as @Pranav mentioned in his answer. It is a better practice, but you will probably have to read up on it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code below to perform that:

```js
$('#paymentTable input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
  $('#paymentTable input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked", false);
  $(this).prop("checked", true);
});
```

Comment: This assumes that he would switch away from calling the function from the HTML event, but it is a very nice and simple solution and probably a better approach to this problem altogether. One thing I'd add is a limited scope and targets, so that it doesn't go through the whole DOM every time someone clicks a `$('input[type=checkbox]')`.

Comment: @Dropout thank you for the appreciation. Actually, with what we are provided with, this was what I could think of. However, you are absolutely right, that the event must trigger for a selective block of code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `change` event of jquery to keep track when your checkbox is checked or unchecked and then we can check if the checkbox is checked if `true` then  use `$('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);` to unchecked other checkboxes.Also i have removed `onclick="resetPaymentDisplay(this);` in below code snippet .

**Demo Code** :

```js
//on change of checkbox
$(document).on("change","input[type=checkbox]" ,function() {
//chcking if checkbox is checked
  if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
  //unchecked others
    $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    console.log("uncheck others")
   
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="paymentTable" class="stripeTwoRows eligibilityARPaymentInfoWidth">
  <div class="row mx-0">
    <div class="col-2 px-1">
      <input id="memberARPaymentchkbox1" type="checkbox" name="memberARPaymentchkbox" payment="216001221" class="cursorPtr"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>216001221
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 px-1">00001</div>
    <div class="col-2 px-1">06/30/2016</div>
    <div class="col-2 px-1"></div>
    <div class="col-2 px-1">N</div>
    <div class="col-2 px-1 d-flex justify-content-end">$350.00-</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row mx-0">
    <div class="col-2 offset-4 px-1">0063016</div>
    <div class="col-2 offset-4 px-1 d-flex justify-content-end">$0.00</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row mx-0">
    <div class="col-2 px-1">
      <input id="memberARPaymentchkbox2" type="checkbox" name="memberARPaymentchkbox" payment="216001222" class="cursorPtr"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>216001222
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 px-1">00001</div>
    <div class="col-2 px-1">06/30/2016</div>
    <div class="col-2 px-1"></div>
    <div class="col-2 px-1">N</div>
    <div class="col-2 px-1 d-flex justify-content-end">$400.00-</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row mx-0">
    <div class="col-2 offset-4 px-1">0063016</div>
    <div class="col-2 offset-4 px-1 d-flex justify-content-end">$0.00</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```html
$(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", true);
```

Comment: That's not working, I mentioned it in the question itself

Comment: You should either be setting .attr("checked", "checked"), or .prop("checked", true)